# `Turn display off after` changes to default automatically

Tags: display, battery, sleep-wake

I set the `Turn display off after` in `System Preferences -> Battery` and `System Preferences -> Power Adapter` to `Never`.

But it changes to `5 min` on its own.

MacBook Pro 2019